How to set relashionship titleattribute based on the locale (fr or ar)
i want to change make the titleattribute of the relashionship based on the (language used)locale (fr or ar for example) using a closure
example: if the locale used is the 'fr' the titleattribute will be 'name' or if the locale is 'ar' the titleattribute will be 'name_ar'
Select::make('permis') ->relationship('permis',  ???  ) ->preload() ->multiple()

thanks in advance

->relationship('permis',function () {
                                            if (app()->getLocale()=='ar'){
                                                return 'name_ar' ;
                                            } else {
                                                return 'name' ;
                                            }
                                        })


While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.
